# Cloud Function, Retry On Failure resets on Deploying function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm having a problem where I need to enable "Retry on failure" on a Pub/Sub cloud function, but whenever I deploy an update to the function I have to manually edit and enable "Retry on failure" for that function.

Is there a configuration or option where it keeps "Retry on failure" enabled until I disable it?

Comment: When you say you have to enable the Retry on Failure option you mean going to the Console and [edit the function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#how_to_enable_retries) there by checking the "Retry on Failure" box?

Answer (score 1):

If you're deploying Google Cloud Functions (not Firebase Cloud Functions, see [this note](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/functions-and-firebase#known_limitations_on_interoperability)), you can now pass the `--retry` flag to your deploy command, such as:

```
gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --retry
```

See [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#using_the_gcloud_command-line_tool) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Official deployment tooling does not seem to support setting retry behavior yet. 
Using the REST API to modify retry behavior after deployment seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash


project=$(gcloud config list project --format="value(core.project)")

function set_retry() {
  curl -X PATCH -d '{"eventTrigger":{"failurePolicy":{"retry": {}}}}' \
    "https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$project/locations/us-central1/functions/$1?updateMask=eventTrigger.failurePolicy&access_token="$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)\
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" -s -o /dev/null
}

gcloud beta functions list --format="value(name)" | while read fn; do
  echo "setting retry policy for function $fn"
  set_retry $fn
done
```

Note that the region is hard-coded to us-central1 above and might need to be changed.